# GCC running version doesn't match emerged version

Tags: linux, gentoo, gcc, version, portage

Here is the output from my portage search for gcc:

`emerge -s gcc`

```
...
*  sys-devel/gcc
      Latest version available: 4.6.3
      Latest version installed: 4.6.3
      Size of files: 70,353 kB
      Homepage:      http://gcc.gnu.org/
      Description:   The GNU Compiler Collection
      License:       GPL-3+ LGPL-3+ || ( GPL-3+ libgcc libstdc++ gcc-runtime-library-exception-3.1 ) FDL-1.3+
...
```

Yet when I do `gcc --version`, I get this:

```
gcc (Gentoo 4.5.4 p1.0, pie-0.4.7) 4.5.4
```

Any ideas? I need to use C++11 for a project I'm trying to compile, but I have no idea what to do. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `gcc-config`. It's basically an eselect version for gcc. Follow the gentoo gcc upgrade guide here:

http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/gcc-upgrading.xml

Answer (score 0):

emerg based on Python and reads standard .ebuild files located in /usr/portage. The ebuild files describes how the source should be configured and installed, depending on variables set in /etc/make.conf.

Maybe in new version of GCC .ebuild file doesn't upgrade. and You see wrong version.

GCC 4.5 Which you have it doesn't support below options:

1. Rvalue references for *this
2. Non-static data member initializers
3. Template aliases
4. Null pointer constant
5. Forward declarations for enums
6. Generalized attributes
7. Generalized constant expressions
8. Alignment support
9. Delegating constructors
10. Inheriting constructors
11. Extended friend declarations
    and many other options...

GCC 4.8 support C++11 fully. Try to upgrade your compiler to latest version.

Comment: Do you know how to change ebuilds so that it will upgrade? Thanks for the help, I'm going to try to `locate` the new gcc version that's been compiled.

Comment: For upgrading your GCC, it's too easy use `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade` in debian base or `yum update` command in redhat base linux. These command updates all old packages.

Comment: I'm using gentoo haha. Hence the emerge/portage stuff haha.